# Semantic UI "No gulpfile found"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I've been trying to install Semantic UI with npm. The website says to run the following code:

```
npm install -g gulp
npm install semantic-ui --save
cd semantic/
gulp build
```

Gulp seems to install correctly, as does Semantic UI. But when I run the last line, I get

```
No gulpfile found
```

I'm not sure what this could be from. Do I need to make a file before I run this command?

Thanks!

Comment: try `npm install  gulp --save-dev`

Comment: @ihemant360 Sadly didn't work :/ thanks though!

Comment: run `gulp install` first then `gulp build`

Comment: @ihemant360 In the project folder? I tried running `gulp install` in both my project folder and in the semantic folder and got the same error message

Comment: check gulp version `CLI version ` and 
 `Local version ` is it same or not ?  `gulp --version`

Comment: @ihemant360 Yep it is, `version 3.9.1` for both

Comment: check npm_module folder. is it inside semantic folder or not. if not copy, and `run gulp build`

Comment: @ihemant360 It was in the semantic folder, but I doubled check and copied it in there again. Unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: at this time i'll say , follow instruction in semantic docs. and reinstall ..

Comment: check if the file called gulpfile.js is in your root directory. and in it code will be something like this [example gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/Raynos/8313682) and for semantic UI [semantic-UI gulpfile](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

Answer (score 0):

### Run `gulp build` from inside of `/semantic` (not root)

Gulp is looking for a gulpfile in the same directory where the command is executed.

So, cd into the `semantic` directory and try running `gulp build` again. It should work as long as you see a `gulpfile.js` file and have followed all the steps from the [Gulp quick start](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/).

Comment: Note: This will only work with Fomantic-UI (the community fork), since semantic-ui itself has conflicts with Node 12 and won't install at all.